# Function not returning Long

Tags: excel, vba

When either of these two ways:

```
MsgBox find_row(ws_month, bs, cat, subcat, item) 
or
dim row as long
row = find_row(ws_month, bs, cat, subcat, item) 
MsgBox row
```

to output this code

```
Function find_row(ws As Worksheet, bs As String, _
 cat As String, subcat As String, item As String) As Long

    Dim vArr As Variant
    Dim iCount As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim tmp As Long

    lr = get_last_row(ws)
    vArr = Range("a1:d" & lr).Value

    For iCount = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
        If vArr(iCount, 1) = bs Then
            If vArr(iCount, 2) = cat Then
                If vArr(iCount, 3) = subcat Then
                    If vArr(iCount, 4) = item Then
                        'MsgBox iCount
                        tmp = iCount
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next iCount

    fing_row = tmp

End Function
```

it returns 0

I have output all var's going into the function to prove valid data is going in but still 0

I have can also print the iCount and tmp from within the function by using a message box but can return the value back to my main code?

Any ideas?

the only thing I have done differently in this code to code I normally use is the addition of LBound and Ubound but I have checked numerous examples and it I'm sure I have that part right

Comment: Also replace `Range("a1:d" & lr).Value` with `Range("a1").Resize(lr,4).Value`

Answer (score 2):

You assign the variable `fing_row` to `tmp`.

Shouldn't you be assigning `find_row = tmp` instead?

**Edit:** 
A good way to avoid making typo's with variables, is by always using [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855.aspx) at the top of your code. If you had used that, it would not have allowed your code to compile (as `fing_row` wouldn't have been declared).

Comment: And the typo :P .  Good catch.

Comment: Oh Dear Lord! How on earth did I miss that!!! Thanks very much! Another one for the guild of dyslexic coders!

Comment: @user3661451 because you don't have Option Explicit turned on.  You really should do that (in the VBA IDE go to Tools => Options and tick the Required Declaration box

Comment: @user3661451 you won't be the last :)